# Using a parameter in a MySQL stored procedure WHERE-CLAUSE slows down performance

Tags: mysql, performance, stored-procedures, parameters, left-join

I have a stored procedure declared as below:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`blabla`@`%` PROCEDURE `getAllDomainsByCountry`(IN dom_id INT)

BEGIN
SELECT 
domain.id,
IFNULL(domain.indexed, '-') AS indexed,
domain.name,
country.language_code,
IFNULL(ip_adress.adress, '-') AS adress,
IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(category.name
            SEPARATOR ', '),
        '-') AS categories,
IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(category.id
            SEPARATOR ', '),
        '-') AS categories_id,
(SELECT 
        IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT client.name
                        SEPARATOR ', '),
                    '-')
    FROM
        link
            LEFT JOIN
        client_site ON link.client_site = client_site.id
            LEFT JOIN
        client ON client.id = client_site.client
    WHERE
        link.from_domain = domain.id) AS clients,
IFNULL(domain_host.name, '-') AS domain_host_account,
IFNULL(content_host.name, '-') AS content_host,
status.id AS status,
status.name AS status_name
FROM
domain
    LEFT JOIN
ip_adress ON domain.ip = ip_adress.id
    LEFT JOIN
domain_category ON domain.id = domain_category.domain
    LEFT JOIN
category ON domain_category.category = category.id
    LEFT JOIN
country ON domain.country = country.id
    LEFT JOIN
domain_host_account ON domain.domain_host_account = domain_host_account.id
    LEFT JOIN
domain_host ON domain_host_account.host = domain_host.id
    LEFT JOIN
content_host ON domain.content_host = content_host.id
    LEFT JOIN
domain_status ON domain.id = domain_status.domain
    LEFT JOIN
status ON domain_status.status = status.id
WHERE
domain.country = dom_id
GROUP BY domain.id
ORDER BY domain.name;  
END
```

If I replace the usage of the parameter dom_id with a static integer, ie:

```
WHERE
  domain.country = 1
```

MySQL version: 5.5.41

EXPLAIN:

```
id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra
1,PRIMARY,domain,ref,idx_domain_country,idx_domain_country,5,const,1858,"Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort"
1,PRIMARY,ip_adress,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,dominfo.domain.ip,1,
1,PRIMARY,domain_category,ref,FK_domain_category_domain_idx,FK_domain_category_domain_idx,5,dominfo.domain.id,1,
1,PRIMARY,category,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,dominfo.domain_category.category,1,
1,PRIMARY,country,const,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,const,1,
1,PRIMARY,domain_host_account,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,dominfo.domain.domain_host_account,1,
1,PRIMARY,domain_host,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,dominfo.domain_host_account.host,1,
1,PRIMARY,content_host,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,dominfo.domain.content_host,1,
1,PRIMARY,domain_status,ALL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1544,
1,PRIMARY,status,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,dominfo.domain_status.status,1,
2,"DEPENDENT SUBQUERY",link,ALL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,8703,"Using where"
2,"DEPENDENT SUBQUERY",client_site,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,dominfo.link.client_site,1,
2,"DEPENDENT SUBQUERY",client,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,dominfo.client_site.client,1,"Using where"
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE domain:

```
CREATE TABLE `domain` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(67) DEFAULT NULL,
`domain_host_account` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`content_host` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`ip` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`historic_content` tinytext,
`redirected` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`ftp_account` tinyint(1) DEFAULT ''0'',
`comment` tinytext,
`country` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`redirected_text` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`status_text` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
`dhost_text` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
`chost_text` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
`category_text` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
`dhost_acc_text` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`indexed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`indexed_checked` date DEFAULT NULL,
`origin` tinyint(1) DEFAULT ''0'',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `FK_domain_host_account_idx` (`domain_host_account`),
KEY `idx_domain_ip` (`ip`),
KEY `idx_domain_country` (`country`),
KEY `idx_domain_domain_host_account` (`domain_host_account`),
KEY `idx_domain_content_host` (`content_host`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12598 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The procedure will take 0.06s to execute whereas using the parameter "dom_id", passing integer value of 1, it will result in an execution time of 5.070s. Any ideas?

Comment: I`ll promote this question if you dont get any answers in 2 days or whatever the interval is.

Comment: Actually your suggestion did work Mihai. Only the first run was 5s, subsequent runs are 0.06s.

Comment: When you change paramter first time is it still slow?

Comment: Yes, if I change parameter to 2 the first run is still slow. The next runs are fast.

Comment: The issue is parameter cache is uses the value for the previous value to get the plan.I dont even know if its possbile to make it fast on the first run

Comment: I will wait a few days and see if I get anymore replies, then I will flag your answer as solution. This issues still doesnt make any sense to me. Why would using a static integer be fast than using a parameter with the very same integer as input?

Comment: The first offer remains,mysqlf I`m curious.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "offer"?

Comment: To put a bounty on your question,a prize in reputation points,like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/need-answers?show=bounties&sort=newest&tagFilter=recommended

Comment: First time -- you hit disk to gather data.  Second time -- it's all cached in RAM, so much faster.  Or... you have the "Query cache" turned on and it does not even rerun the query.

Comment: What version of mysql are you running?

Comment: Can you get an EXPLAIN of the query?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE domain;`.

Comment: Question updated with requested info.

Comment: @sboss : could please verify reason for such slow behavior mentioned in my answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go dynamic go all the way,I used testing not to overwrite your original proc,also make sure you dont have a `testing` proc already there

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `testing`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `testing`(IN `test` INT)
 BEGIN
SET @id=test;
SET @query="SELECT 
domain.id,
IFNULL(domain.indexed, '-') AS indexed,
domain.name,
country.language_code,
IFNULL(ip_adress.adress, '-') AS adress,
IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(category.name
            SEPARATOR ', '),
        '-') AS categories,
IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(category.id
            SEPARATOR ', '),
        '-') AS categories_id,
(SELECT 
        IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT client.name
                        SEPARATOR ', '),
                    '-')
    FROM
        link
            LEFT JOIN
        client_site ON link.client_site = client_site.id
            LEFT JOIN
        client ON client.id = client_site.client
    WHERE
        link.from_domain = domain.id) AS clients,
IFNULL(domain_host.name, '-') AS domain_host_account,
IFNULL(content_host.name, '-') AS content_host,
status.id AS status,
status.name AS status_name
FROM
domain
    LEFT JOIN
ip_adress ON domain.ip = ip_adress.id
    LEFT JOIN
domain_category ON domain.id = domain_category.domain
    LEFT JOIN
category ON domain_category.category = category.id
    LEFT JOIN
country ON domain.country = country.id
    LEFT JOIN
domain_host_account ON domain.domain_host_account = domain_host_account.id
    LEFT JOIN
domain_host ON domain_host_account.host = domain_host.id
    LEFT JOIN
content_host ON domain.content_host = content_host.id
    LEFT JOIN
domain_status ON domain.id = domain_status.domain
    LEFT JOIN
status ON domain_status.status = status.id
WHERE
domain.country = ?
GROUP BY domain.id
ORDER BY domain.name;"  

PREPARE sqlquery FROM @query;
EXECUTE sqlquery USING @id;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Then use

```
CALL `testing`(1);
```

Comment: and `DEALLOCATE PREPARE`.

Comment: This is what I ended up using and its working as expected!

Answer (score 8):

As per the question, @sboss wants to know the behaviour of :

```
The procedure will take 0.06s to execute with static int whereas using the parameter 
"dom_id", passing integer value of 1, it will result in an execution 
time of 5.070s.
```

This behaviour can be easily understood, if we see how mysql engine works.

> MySQL engine caches query and result. The query cache stores the text
>   of a SELECT statement together with the corresponding result that was
>   sent to the client. If an identical statement is received later, the
>   server retrieves the results from the query cache rather than parsing
>   and executing the statement again.

Hence, it is most likely in your case that `execution time of 5.070s` is found when query actually parsed and executed by mysql engine and `execution time of 0.06s` is found when result-set was retrieved from query cache.

Kindly refer documentation for detail : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache.html

Answer (score 5):

**Optimization 1**

Part of the slowdown is the repeatedly executed "dependent subquery":

```
      ( SELECT  IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT client.name SEPARATOR ', '), '-')
            FROM  link
            LEFT JOIN  client_site ON link.client_site = client_site.id
            LEFT JOIN  client ON client.id = client_site.client
            WHERE  link.from_domain = domain.id
      ) AS clients
```

According to the `EXPLAIN`, it must scan all ~8703 rows of `link` each time.

I don't think it can be simplified within the same query.  Instead I think this will be useful:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t_clients (
    PRIMARY KEY(from_domain)
)
    SELECT  link.from_domain,
            IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT client.name SEPARATOR ', '), '-')
        FROM  link
        LEFT JOIN  client_site ON link.client_site = client_site.id
        LEFT JOIN  client ON client.id = client_site.client;
```

Then

```
SELECT  domain.id, IFNULL(domain.indexed, '-') AS indexed, domain.name,
        country.language_code, IFNULL(ip_adress.adress, '-') AS adress,
        IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(category.name SEPARATOR ', '), '-') AS categories,
        IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(category.id SEPARATOR ', '), '-') AS categories_id,
        t_clients.clients AS clients,                          -- Changed
        IFNULL(domain_host.name, '-') AS domain_host_account,
        IFNULL(content_host.name, '-') AS content_host,
        status.id AS status, status.name AS status_name
    FROM  domain
    LEFT JOIN t_clients  ON t_clients.from_domain = domain.id  -- Added
    LEFT JOIN  ip_adress ON domain.ip = ip_adress.id
    LEFT JOIN  domain_category ON domain.id = domain_category.domain
    LEFT JOIN  category ON domain_category.category = category.id
    LEFT JOIN  country ON domain.country = country.id
    LEFT JOIN  domain_host_account ON domain.domain_host_account = domain_host_account.id
    LEFT JOIN  domain_host ON domain_host_account.host = domain_host.id
    LEFT JOIN  content_host ON domain.content_host = content_host.id
    LEFT JOIN  domain_status ON domain.id = domain_status.domain
    LEFT JOIN  status ON domain_status.status = status.id
    WHERE  domain.country = dom_id
    GROUP BY  domain.id
    ORDER BY  domain.name;
```

You can experiment as to whether the `PREPARE` approach is faster.  In one (simpler) test I did, it did not seem to matter.

**Optimization 2**

Another *potential* speedup is to do the `GROUP_CONCATs` in subqueries *instead* of collecting lots of rows, then collapsing.  Note that you had to use `GROUP BY`.  This technique may be able to eliminate that.  For example:

```
IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(category.name SEPARATOR ', '), '-') AS categories,
LEFT JOIN category ON ...
```

-->

```
IFNULL(
    ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(category.name SEPARATOR ', ')
          FROM category
          WHERE category.id = domain_category.category
    ),
'-') AS categories,
```

The reason why it *might* be can be observed if you do this with both your variant and with my variant:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( the select, but without the GROUP BY or ORDER BY );
```

Your variant will (assuming lots of categories, etc) will have a much larger `COUNT`.  That implies that your query is building a much bigger tmp table to feed to `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`.  Hence slower.

**Optimization 3**

If you manage to get rid of all the aggregates (`GROUP_CONCAT`), then adding `INDEX(country, name)` should further optimize it by getting rid of the two `FILESORTs`.

Answer (score 0):

you are saying here that you are able to get the data where quick while you use WHERE
  domain.country = 1 
instead of 
WHERE
  domain.country = dom_id
but I am not able to see where clause on domain.country in your query. can you please clarify this.

But in general what happen is

1. Where clause runs faster on integer values
2. If you are performing where clause on any column very frequently than you can index that column. Indexing helps alot in faster retrieval. But at the same time you need to take a wise decision while indexing columns.

Please let me know if you are looking for anything else.

Comment: The where clause is 5th line from bottom, perhaps you didnt scroll?  
1. Yes but why? The parameter is an integer as well.
2. This column is indexed.

Comment: Did you tried passing 1 as argument for dom_id ? and tested the response time? it should be same I guess

Comment: This is exactly what I did, sorry if I was not clear. I did pass the very same integer value as the parameter and the execution time was 16x slower.

Comment: Hmmm... This is strange. This should not happen at all. Will try to see if mysql has documented something on this

Answer (score 0):

First clear your doubt why query is taking time if passing value through parameter. As Rick and Jaydatt have mentioned in their posts that it can be due to query cache, so you can first clear your this doubt by executing your query with addition SQL_NO_CACHE keyword like `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE domain.id, IFNULL(domain.indexed, '-') AS indexed,....`

I think now you should get approx. same time by both queries.

Further for optimization of this query even Rick has provided you so many useful options you can check below option also along with those.

First check if link.from_domain field is indexed or not as explain is showing that all rows are scanning from link table.

You can also check your query performance with below approach-

```
SELECT 
domain.id,
IFNULL(domain.indexed, '-') AS indexed,
domain.name,
country.language_code,
IFNULL(ip_adress.adress, '-') AS adress,
IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(category.name
            SEPARATOR ', '),
        '-') AS categories,
IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(category.id
            SEPARATOR ', '),
        '-') AS categories_id,
(SELECT 
        IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT client.name
                        SEPARATOR ', '),
                    '-')
    FROM
        link
            LEFT JOIN
        client_site ON link.client_site = client_site.id
            LEFT JOIN
        CLIENT ON client.id = client_site.client
    WHERE
        link.from_domain = domain.id) AS clients,
IFNULL(domain_host.name, '-') AS domain_host_account,
IFNULL(content_host.name, '-') AS content_host,
status.id AS STATUS,
status.name AS status_name
FROM
(
SELECT id,indexed,`name`,ip,country,domain_host_account,content_host 
FROM domain 
WHERE country = dom_id
) AS domain
    LEFT JOIN
ip_adress ON domain.ip = ip_adress.id
    LEFT JOIN
domain_category ON domain.id = domain_category.domain
    LEFT JOIN
category ON domain_category.category = category.id
    LEFT JOIN
country ON domain.country = country.id
    LEFT JOIN
domain_host_account ON domain.domain_host_account = domain_host_account.id
    LEFT JOIN
domain_host ON domain_host_account.host = domain_host.id
    LEFT JOIN
content_host ON domain.content_host = content_host.id
    LEFT JOIN
domain_status ON domain.id = domain_status.domain
    LEFT JOIN
STATUS ON domain_status.status = status.id
GROUP BY domain.id
ORDER BY domain.name;
```